# Creating network of terms of maximum occuring terms in R language

Tags: r

I am creating network of terms from a file which contains text data. I have been successful in making network but it is making network of all words from file(say 1281 words). I want network of maximum times occurring words from a data file.
Following is code I tried.

```
text<-read.delim(file='check.csv', header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
a <- Corpus(VectorSource(text), readerControl = list(language = "en"))

a <- tm_map(a, removeNumbers)
a<- tm_map(a, gsub, pattern=",", replacement=" ")
a <- tm_map(a, removePunctuation)
a <- tm_map(a , stripWhitespace)
a <- tm_map(a, tolower)
a <- tm_map(a, removeWords, stopwords("english")) 
a <- tm_map(a, removeWords, c("cox","can","cant","get","set") )



newtext <- lapply(a, function(x){
  x <- Corpus(VectorSource(x))
  x1 <- x
  x <- tm_map(x, stemDocument, language = "english")
  x <- tm_map(x, stemCompletion, dictionary=x1)  
} 
)
newtext1 <- Corpus(VectorSource(newtext))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(newtext1)
termDocMatrix<-tdm
termDocMatrix<-as.matrix(termDocMatrix)
termMatrix<-termDocMatrix %*% t(termDocMatrix) # term-term adjacency matrix
library(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency(termMatrix, weighted=T, mode="undirected")
g <- simplify(g) # remove loops
V(g)$name
V(g)$label <- V(g)$name
V(g)$degree <- degree(g)
set.seed(3952)
layout1 <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
plot.new()
plot(g, layout=layout1)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please give packages used - `Corpus` , `tm_map`, among other functions not defined here.  More important - what part of this code is supposed to be filtering words by frequency?

Comment: ok @CarlWitthoft 
library(tm) 

library(ggplot2)

library(RColorBrewer)

these packages I have used.

Actually I want those words which occures in file maximum time. And I want to make network of only those terms.